# hive table shows 0 results while querying

Tags: hadoop, hive

My hive table is a managed table and i can see the files present in HDFS.
While querying through hive it does not display any result.

```
hive> describe formatted emp

Result - 
| Table Type:                     | MANAGED_TABLE                                      
| Table Parameters:               | NULL                                               
| 2                               | bucketing_version                                  
| 1376                            | numFiles                                           
| 43                              | numPartitions                                      
| 0                               | numRows                                            
| gzip                            | parquet.compression                                
| 0                               | rawDataSize                                        
| 4770821594                      | totalSize                                          
| true                            | transactional                                      
| insert_only                     | transactional_properties                           
| 1612857428                      | transient_lastDdlTime
```

While selecting data from table -
select * from emp;
it fetches no results.
Why there is difference in HDFS and select output.

Comment: How did you created and loaded that table?

Comment: Try to run recover partitions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033175/2700344

Comment: or try analyze table compute statistics.

Comment: @leftjoin - Table is created by hive shell and loaded from another hive table.

Comment: I can not execute ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME RECOVER PARTITIONS command on table. It gives error "Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:34 cannot recognize input near 'RECOVER' 'PARTITIONS' '<EOF>' in alter table statement (state=42000,code=40000"

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin, koushik - ANALYZE TABLE table_name COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;  worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Command worked for me -

```
ANALYZE TABLE table_name COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
```

Comment: This is strange. select all should work without statistics. select count(*) can use stats.